# Vb.net tcplistener as a service

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have written a code that works as a ftp **windows service** in vb.net and when a client request to connect it through my local address in same computer it works but when the request is from a camera to ftp picture to it with its own ip address it doesn't work.
In advance, I would appreciate it if you answer me.